# OVER ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW not working. Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
  dTotalCharge,
  iCarrierInvoiceDetailsID,
  dtPickupDate,
  vcTrackingNum,
  SUM(dTotalCharge) OVER (PARTITION BY iCarrierInvoiceDetailsID
  ORDER BY dtPickupDate, vcTrackingNum
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS runningTotal
FROM tblCID
```

Getting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.

Any idea what is wrong with this. I had another problem before `PIVOT` before. These are examples out of `70-461` Training Kit. I am confused.

Comment: Does the query work without the window clause?  That is the default window.

Comment: This ROW-clause is not be used before SQL Server 2012...

Comment: So it is ROW. 2008R2. How would i use windows function in this manner?

Comment: @bones The OVER clause with a ROW or RANGE clause was introduced in SQL Server 2012. Consult the [answers to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver).

Comment: @bones Obviously, I meant for versions prior to SQL Server 2012, consult the link :)